# Can't connect SQLAlchemy with pyodbc to Microsoft Access database

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a Microsoft Access .accdb database which I am trying to access using sqlalchemy and pyodbc. When I create a connection and cursor using pyodbc alone, everything works fine, however I would prefer to use sqlalchemy, which throws an error and I am not sure why.

The below code works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

database_connector = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<database_file_path>"
    
with pyodbc.connect(database_connector) as con:
    query = "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Table"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

However, the below code does not:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
import pandas as pd

database_connector = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<database_file_path>"

url = URL.create(
    drivername="mssql+pyodbc",
    query={
        "odbc_connect": database_connector,
    },
)

with create_engine(url).connect() as con:
    query = text("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Table")
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, con)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error when `create_engine(url).connect()` is executed:

> Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Undefined function 'schema_name' in expression. (-3102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
> [SQL: SELECT schema_name()]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mssql+pyodbc` is for Microsoft SQL Server. You need to install [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) and use `access+pyodbc`.

(I maintain the sqlalchemy-access dialect.)

Comment: Knew it would be something trivial... thanks so much !